# Catalog of programs listed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In bash (or any other shell), when you type "firefox" or another command, how does bash point it to its actual location (/usr/bin/firefox)? Also, where is the "catalog" for bash autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `$PATH` variable that holds all paths (colon-separated) to lookup for command names. Those folders are checked from the first one to the last one and command is executed when found (so if there are multiple files of that name in different `$PATH` directories, the first one will be executed).

To view `$PATH`:

```
echo $PATH
```

To check where `firefox` is:

```
which firefox
```

Comment: If it happens that there are commands with the same name, but in different folders (both in `$PATH`), you can use `which -a firefox` to list all of them. On execution, the shell picks the first one.

Comment: so how would someone add a program to $path or am I understanding this wrongly? Also, is there an actual file?

Comment: $PATH folders are looked up when you issue a command. When file is found, it's executed. To "create" a new command, add an executable file of that name to any PATH-ed directory. You can also create a new dir with that file and add the dir to $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` and other shells and command processors search your [`PATH` directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), looking for an executable file that matches the command name you've typed.

Answer (score 1):

The essentials are already given in the other answers. Technically, the shell stores the location of a command in a hash table. In `bash` you can view this table by the command `hash`:

```
$ hash
hits    command
   2    /usr/bin/ldd
   1    /usr/bin/man
   1    /usr/bin/less
```

You can also modify this hash table, for details I quote the `bash` man page:

> ```
> hash [-lr] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]
> ```
>
> For each name, the full file name of the command is determined by searching the directories in $PATH and remembered.   If
>                 the  -p  option is supplied, no path search is performed, and filename is used as the full file name of the command. 
>   The
>                 -r option causes the shell to forget all remembered locations.  The -d option causes the shell to forget  the  remembered
>                 location  of  each  name.  If the -t option is supplied, the full pathname to which each name corresponds is printed.  If
>                 multiple name arguments are supplied with -t, the name is printed before the hashed full pathname.  The -l option  causes
>                 output  to  be  displayed in a format that may be reused as input.  If no arguments are given, or if only -l is supplied,
>                 information about remembered commands is printed.  The return status is true unless a name is not  found  or  an  invalid
>                 option is supplied. Here you can see, which commands you already executed in this session.

Other shells can behave differently, in `zsh` (and I think this was adapted from `csh`) the shell gathers all command at startup or by invoking `rehash`. Then you get a complete list of all available commands with `hash` and you can search e.g. for all variants of `diff`:

```
zsh$ hash | grep diff
bzdiff=/usr/bin/bzdiff
cdiff=/usr/bin/cdiff
colordiff=/usr/bin/colordiff
diff=/usr/bin/diff
diff3=/usr/bin/diff3
ptardiff=/usr/bin/ptardiff
sdiff=/usr/bin/sdiff
tkdiff=/usr/bin/tkdiff
vimdiff=/usr/bin/vimdiff
xzdiff=/usr/bin/xzdiff
zdiff=/usr/bin/zdiff
```

Again, consult `man zshbuiltins` for much more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. bash uses the `$PATH` environment variable to look for programs by word.  Paths are separated by `:`.  Your `$PATH` is most likely something like `:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/games:`, so it finds it in `/usr/local/bin`.  Change your `$PATH` and try again.
2. You can change tab completion behavior via the `complete` builtin.  See the "Programmable Completion" of `man bash`.