# Why do I need a "./" before executing some scripts?

Tags: unix, shell

For instance, I have installed java and can just run `java ...` but if I create a shell script for instance, I have to run `./script.sh`.

Why is this? What does the `./` signify?

Comment: This answer on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6331085) covers it very well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an executable is not in the PATH , you need to specify the path explicitly. `./` is a "relative" path specifier: "starting from here (`.`) go "no further" (`/`). If you add the current directory to your PATH environment variable and issue `rehash` command, you will no longer need it.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a command, the shell searches the `PATH` variable (or some hash table, depending on the shell<sup>#</sup>) where to find the executable. But usually the current working directory (`.`) isn't included. So, you need to tell the shell where to find your script by prepending `./` as explained by Floris.

The purpose of that default setting is, that you are saved from accidentally executing a script (in the current dir) which is named e.g. `rm` instead of the expected command in `/bin`. This is especially crucial for root, because the local script can behave completely different as you'll expect it!

---

<sup>#</sup> I wrote a little bit more about hash tables in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/559528/195224).

Answer (score 1):

Current directory is not normaly in PATH, so commands will not lookup from current directory by default

Comment: Just as extra information: There is a reason why it is not in your path by default, and why you should always put it last if you add it. (Imaging me having a program called `ls` or `dir` in my homedir. If you visit my homedir ans try to list the contents then you really want the system file, not the one in my homedir).

Answer (score 1):

`java` is in your `$PATH` variable so that is why it is found and executed. `./` tells the command line to use the file in your current directory which is usually not on the PATH.